# How can I extract an array in Json and export it to excel?

Tags: reactjs, excel

In my case, I have a REST server that I receive an json response:

```json
[
        {
            "Request Id": "99616040-83a7-4e05-86b0-cc5ccf1ccb3c",
            "Similar": true
            "Faces": [
                {
                    "Image Id": "90817338-d83b-4168-b4bf-98f16b18cdae",
                    "Score": 1
                },
                {
                    "Image Id": "28f81e46-dda5-4f85-bdfc-0b7723a3e04f",
                    "Score": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
]
```

With my ReacJS client, I use `xlsx` and `file-saver` to export excel file.

```js
const exportToCSV = (csvData, fileName) => {

            const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
            const fileExtension = '.xlsx';

            const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(csvData);
            const wb = {Sheets: {'data': ws}, SheetNames: ['data']};
            const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array'});
            // let readUTF8 = excelBuffer.toString('utf8')
            const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], {type: fileType});
            FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);
}
exportToCSV(response.data, "export")
```

It work and I have an excel file with `Request Id`, `Similar` and `Faces` columns.

But the `Faces` column has no data

How can I get data of `Faces` in json array and fill it as Excel column?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Perhaps the easiest approach is to use Power Query.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/parse-json-xml

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it is so easy for me but if I stand at view of end user, I should build an feature which will export an excel file with transparent columns. So, Processing in my scripts is needed @@